# Execute multiple queries at once in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

I am trying to combine two queries in Mongoose into one.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
User.find({ _id: req.body.userId }, (err, user) => {
  User.find({ username: decodedUser.username }, (err, member) => {
   console.log("user\n", user)
   console.log("member\n", member)
 })
})
```

I'd like to make a single `User.find()` query to the database, and the result be an object (or an array) of all the documents that I want, such as an array of `[user, member]` in this case.  This will save me from having to run `User.find()` twice.  Ideally, I'd like the result from the query to be an object so that I can find a specific key/value set more easily, as opposed to an array that I would have to iterate through to find a particular element.  **How do I do this?**

Note: this works:

```
User.find({ $or:
  [
    { _id: req.body.userId },
    { username: decodedUser.username}
  ]}, (err, results) => {
  console.log("results\n", results)
})
```

where `results` is an array of the documents that I want.  But, I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are expecting only one result by both of your conditions then you could use `User.findOne` - it will return the first found result.

```
User.findOne({ $or:
  [
    { _id: req.body.userId },
    { username: decodedUser.username}
  ]}, (err, user) => {
  console.log("user\n", user)
})
```

**Edit**

Since you said that you need to get 2 results and you want to have then in the result you can also run 2 queries in parallel and use promises to get the result. E.g.

```
Promise.all([
  User.find({ _id: req.body.userId }),
  User.find({ username: decodedUser.username})
]).then( ([ user, member ]) => {
  console.log( util.format( "user=%O member=%O", user, member ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm actually expecting two results.  The end goal is to run two `User.find()` queries in one execution, rather than executing `User.find()` twice as in my example above, if that makes sense.

Comment: Then your solution looks the best to me

Comment: Yes!  Your "Edit" is *exactly* what I've been trying to do.  Oh man, thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does your last line, `console.log( util.format( "user=%O member=%O", user, member ) );`, do?  Just tried running it locally, and nothing was outputted in my terminal.  Specifically, I'm not really familiar with `util.format`.

Comment: You need to have `const util = require('util');` this is a standard NodeJS utility service. Check the docs here: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html